# "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file *FileName* failed." error after moving from ASP.NET Dev Server to IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, connection-string

My ASP.NET project has an MDF database in App_Data folder.

The connection string is:

> Data
>   Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MainDatabase.mdf;Integrated
>   Security=True;User Instance=True

It worked fine until I changed the project parameters to use "Local IIS Web server" instead of "Visual Studio Development Server".

The project now produces the following `SqlException`:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\SL\SL\App_Data\MainDatabase.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

How to modify the connection string to make it work with IIS?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably find this is file permissions (the error does state: "*or specified file cannot be opened*"). IIS runs as a limited-user by default, and it's unlikely to have access to the Administrators home directory.

Your three options are:

1. Change the identity of the application pool in IIS to run as a user that
   does have access to that folder
2. Move the MDF file to a location that
   IIS can access (and then check the permissions of the file)
3. Change the permissions of the file (and possibly the directories above it) so that IIS can access the file.

Of these, number 2 is the most desirable. The other two reduce security somewhat - the first, by giving IIS free reign over a lot of the file system (and potentially system resources as well); whilst the third has the potential to open up a user's home directory to IIS.

Comment: Just tried giving Everyone Full Control over the directory where the database file is located.. Still fails for some reason.

Comment: You could verify the issue is still permissions by trying option 1 that Chris presented. As he stated, this is very unsafe and shouldn't be used for anything other than testing. If you change the app pool user to your account, and the site works, you know you still have a problem with permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Integrated Security, the user connecting has to map to a SQL Server login.  When you changed to IIS, you switched the user and it may not map to a login in the DB.  You could test this by specifying a username and password that are valid in your database.

For example:

Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MainDatabase.mdf;User Id=admin;Password=password;User Instance=True

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user account your IIS process is running as has correct permissions to that file.